# Why does my Wi-Fi router offer two SSIDs to connect to?

Tags: router, wifi-configuration

My Wi-Fi router offers two Wi-Fi networks to connect to, one that is called `ssid-network` and the other one is called `ssid-network-5G`?

Does one offer faster speeds? What is the need for two ? I’m confused.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your router has two radios inside it. One operates at 2.4GHz and is using the SSID "ssid-network". The other operates at 5GHz and is using the SSID "ssid-network-5G".

The 2.4GHz network is supported by more devices and has longer range. The 5GHz network has higher speed and is typically subject to much less interference, but range is typically lower and not all devices support it.

Comment: There isn't technically any reason in wifi why 5Ghz needs a separate SSID except that automatic choosing of one or the other is undefined and routers often set them up as entirely separate configurations.